# Is it possible to create a bumpy border with 1 object and 1 gradientbrush in XAML?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I need to achieve something like the following in xaml (with nicer corners). I am curious whether it is possible to do it with 1 object (rectangle, path, ....)  and 1 gradientbrush. I haven't found a way so far.

[image: bumpy border example]

Comment: Why do you need it to be a single brush and a single object?

Comment: That is not a hard constraint, I am just curious if it is possible

Answer (score 0):

I see no way of doing this using a single element and a single brush unless you create a brush using a custom pixelshader.

Also, I see no good reason why a single element would be a requirement unless you are adding many frames like this and therefore need to be frugal in the amount of elements you are adding to the visual tree.